# Load overwrites input text box when using callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am programming a 'add to cart' button that makes an ajax call to the database and on success returns the valid data.  After returning the data I want to have it load an HTML file and the run a callback function to populate the input fields with the ajax data.

**My problem**: When the callback runs it overwrites the prior HTML values.

AJAX:

```
success: function(data) {
    $('.upc').val('');
    $('#cart').append(
        $('<div />').load('views/sale/_addItem.php',function(){
            $('#qty').val('1');
            $('#upc').val(data['upc']);
            $('#name').val(data['name']);
            $('#price').val(data['price']);
        })
    );
```

_addItem.php File

```
<input id="qty" type="text" value="" name="qty[]">
<input id="upc" type="text" value="" name="upc[]" disabled>
<input id="name" type="text" value="" name="name[]" disabled>
<input id="price" type="text" value="" name="price[]" disabled>
<input id="extprice" type="text" value="" name="extprice[]" disabled>
<br/>
```

[**Here is the gist.  Removed unnecessary code.**](https://gist.github.com/cgsmith/7792758)

Edit: I don't know why this is getting downvotes.  I am looking at what is the best way to handle this.

Comment: `When the callback runs it overwrites the prior HTML values.` that's what it's supposed to do... unless you mean on second iteration, at which point your markup will be invalid due to duplicate id's.

Comment: @KevinB I mean on the second iteration.  I am at a loss as to how to properly handle the IDs using this method.  Am I better off having the HTML in a variable in the js instead of calling load()?

Comment: first, remove the id's completely if they aren't going to be unique. Now, without id's, how do you select the inputs? (hint: they're all within `$("<div />")`)

Comment: @KevinB I think this is on the right track, no?  `$('<div />').load('views/sale/_addItem.php',function(){
                            $('input[name="qty[]"]:last').val(data['name']);`

Comment: It could work, i would instead store $("<div />") in a temporary variable, then find the input within it in the callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try using templates, they may work a bit better for you.  Define your HTML as a template and call it to append it on complete or success.

[understanding Jquery template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487647/understanding-jquery-template)