# Pass javascript variable to appended row in Dynamic form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am working with dynamic form.

I want to pass javascript value to append row. Here how can I pass uid value to appended row. I tried `<?php echo $uid = "<script>document.write(uid)</script>";  ?>` in append row.

Bbut it is not working.
Here is my code

*default row*

```html
<div class="form-group row">
  <?php $uid = '1';?>
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Item</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="inputc" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="box-tools">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnAddMoreSpecification" data-original-title="Add More">
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divSpecificatiion">
</div>
```

*Append row*

```html
<script type="text/template" id="temSpecification">
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <?php $uid ='';  ?>

    <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Item</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="inputc" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
    </div>

    <div class="box-tools">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnRemoveMoreSpecification" data-original-title="Add More">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function (event) {
uid=1;uvd=2;$('#btnAddMoreSpecification').click(function ()
{$('#divSpecificatiion').append($('#temSpecification').html());uid++;uvd++; });

 $(document).on('click', '.btnRemoveMoreSpecification', function () {
      $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
 });
});
```

Output should be like this

[image: output should be like this]

Comment: The problem is that the php will only help until the page is sent to the client. From there client javascript (jquery) will take over. Therefore the php cannot  change the variable in your template. I think this question gives a good background on how to use the template in combination with jquery: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487647/understanding-jquery-template . Thanks for introducing me to this cool technique of templating.

Comment: crash course in difference between php and javascript => php can't be executed on the client side, and javascript(except node.js) can't be executed on the server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(event) {
  uid = 1;
  uvd = 2;
  $('#btnAddMoreSpecification').click(function() {
uid++;
    var templateHtml = $('#temSpecification').html();//save the html in a variable
    var temp = $(templateHtml).find('input[type="text"]').val(uid).end();//find the input and append the new uid
    $('#divSpecificatiion').append(temp);//append the new html to the div
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btnRemoveMoreSpecification', function() {
    $(this).parent('div').parent('div').remove();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group row">
  <?php $uid = '1';?>
  <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Item</label>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="inputc" value="<?php echo $uid;?>">
  </div>

  <div class="box-tools">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnAddMoreSpecification" data-original-title="Add More">Add more
      <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="divSpecificatiion">
</div>


<script type="text/template" id="temSpecification">
  <div class="form-group row" style="padding-top:10px;">

    <?php $uid ='';  ?>

    <label for="name" class="col-sm-1 form-control-label">Item</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="" id="inputc" value="">
    </div>

    <div class="box-tools">
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm btnRemoveMoreSpecification" data-original-title="Add More">
        <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</script>
```