# Reload a content table with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I developed a table that on load generates dynamically with PHP and mysql its row. Now what I really want is to refresh only the tbody elements with Jquery after the click of a button. I have written the comment in CAPITAL where I would like to do this. This is the code of the button:

```
 $('#confirm').click(function() {

                            var application = $('#discSwList').val();

                                            $.ajax({
                                                type:'POST',
                                                url:'utility.php',
                                                data: {  unlockFlag: 1, appName: application, arrayCompSw: JSON.stringify(containerList)},
                                                success : function() {
                                                    alert('Everything is fine');
// IN THE FOLLOWING STATEMENT I WOULD LIKE TO RELOAD ONLY THE tbody called "compSwDiscoveredList" 
                                                    $('#compSwDiscoveredList').load('') ?????
                                                },
                                                error: function(err) {
                                                    alert(err);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });

                                    });
```

The html table:

```
<table id="tableCompSwDiscoveredList" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>Disassocia</th>
                                        <th>ID SW CONFIG</th>
                                        <th>ID SOFTWARE</th>
                                        <th>SO</th>
                                        <th>ID CONFIG</th>
                                        <th>NOME APPARATO</th>
                                        <th>IP ADDRESS</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="compSwDiscoveredList">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Comment: It would be worthwhile for you to look into jQuery's `.load` function. http://api.jquery.com/load/

Comment: I tried to do something like $("#compSwDiscoveredList").load(window.href.location + "#compSwDiscoveredList") but it reload THE WHOLE page inside the tbody :(

Comment: Add your HTML for your table

Comment: @snack_overflow added right now. The content is loaded with ajax

Comment: @EmilioAlfieri to populate table content from JSON data you have to create html or you jquery template. here is the link you can take help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487647/understanding-jquery-template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To populate html content from json you can you jquery template library. I have changed your function with jquery template code

```
    $('#confirm').click(function() {

                            var application = $('#discSwList').val();

                                            $.ajax({
                                                type:'POST',
                                                url:'utility.php',
                                                data: {  unlockFlag: 1, appName: application, arrayCompSw: JSON.stringify(containerList)},
                                                success : function(jsonData) {
                                                    alert('Everything is fine');
// Below "compSwDiscoveredList" 
                                                     $("#tableTemplate").tmpl(jsonData).appendTo("#tableCompSwDiscoveredList");
                                                },
                                                error: function(err) {
                                                    alert(err);
                                                }
                                            });
                                        });

                                    });
```

```js
var jsonData = [
       { Disassocia: "Disassocia1", IdSwConfig: "IdSwConfig1" ,IdSoftware : "IdSoftware1" ,So:'So1' ,IdConfig:'IdConfig1',NomeApparato:'Nome Apparato1',IpAddress:'Ip Address1'},
       { Disassocia: "Disassocia2", IdSwConfig: "IdSwConfig2" ,IdSoftware : "IdSoftware2" ,So:'So2' ,IdConfig:'IdConfig2',NomeApparato:'Nome Apparato2',IpAddress:'Ip Address2'},
       { Disassocia: "Disassocia3", IdSwConfig: "IdSwConfig3" ,IdSoftware : "IdSoftware3" ,So:'So3' ,IdConfig:'IdConfig3',NomeApparato:'Nome Apparato3',IpAddress:'Ip Address3'},
       { Disassocia: "Disassocia4", IdSwConfig: "IdSwConfig4" ,IdSoftware : "IdSoftware4" ,So:'So4' ,IdConfig:'IdConfig4',NomeApparato:'Nome Apparato4',IpAddress:'Ip Address4'} 
       ];
              
              $("#tableTemplate").tmpl(jsonData).appendTo("#tableCompSwDiscoveredList");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>
<script id="tableTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
        <tr>
   <td>${Disassocia}</td>
   <td>${IdSwConfig}</td>
   <td>${IdSoftware}</td>
   <td>${So}</td>
   <td>${IdConfig}</td>
   <td>${NomeApparato}</td>
   <td>${IpAddress}</td>
        </tr>
    </script>
<table id="tableCompSwDiscoveredList" cellspacing="4" cellpadding="4">
                                    <thead>
                                        <th>Disassocia</th>
                                        <th>ID SW CONFIG</th>
                                        <th>ID SOFTWARE</th>
                                        <th>SO</th>
                                        <th>ID CONFIG</th>
                                        <th>NOME APPARATO</th>
                                        <th>IP ADDRESS</th>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody id="compSwDiscoveredList">
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#compSwDiscoveredList').load('asset_discSoftwList.php ' + #compSwDiscoveredList + " > * ", function () {
// something
});
```

This calls the PHP file that generates your dynamic content and inserts it into the div.

Hope this helps.

Comment: nope... it doesn't work because I put a flag in my php page so the content inside the "if statement" will never being executed. Anyway can you check my sintax, please?

Comment: $('#compSwDiscoveredList').load('asset_discSoftwList.php' + #compSwDiscoveredList + " > * ", function () {});

Comment: @EmilioAlfieri - I've updated my answer to include your code, you needed a space after your PHP file